# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification, After switch system

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, version

After switch my system (Android studio version 2.2.2 - 2.3.1). I got this error message. I am able to run my app. but I can't generate signed APK that time I am getting this error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bykar.bykar_provider"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.9.25"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
}
```

Dependency tree

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.6.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:9.6.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.6.1
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1 (*)
|    |              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-module:9.6.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-module:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-module:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:9.6.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.6.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.6.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.6.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
+--- com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0
\--- testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+ -> 1.4.14
```

Comment: you need all your support libs to be of the same version. Check your dependency tree by running ./gradlew app:Dependencies. Also upgrade support libs to 25.3.1

Comment: @Raghunandan I have updated the question with dependency tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.4.14'
```

Also don't use

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

use the latest 10.2.1. Also use specific services instead of the entire package.

Check table 1 at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Testing- dependency tree after- All support libs are 25.3.1

Note - for testing i din't include play services lib.

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
\--- testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.4.14
```

Edit 1:

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bykar.bykar_provider"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.9.25"
```

Edit 2:

Add the below in proguard-rules.pro as documented at https://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html

```
-keep class com.testfairy.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.testfairy.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, LineNumberTabl
```

Comment: getting this error : /Users/jihinraju/Workspace/bykar/bykar-android-provider/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

Comment: getting this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: @JihinRaju have configure proguard rules in release mode. Since you have  **release {
            minifyEnabled true** proguard shrinks and obfuscates your code.

Comment: @JihinRaju Look at https://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html. They ask you to enter **-keep class com.testfairy.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.testfairy.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, LineNumberTable**. Similarly you need to do for all other third party libs and sdks. Don't worry about support libs cause you have some default rules from the sdk